# How to make just one right justified nav element not to collapse on mobile devices?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a navbar with a bunch of navs. I want just the notifications dropdown to not be collapsed on xs devices. I also need the notifications to be in the specific position (to the right of the search form).

Here is the original nav:

```
  <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" role="navigation">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="/"><span class="logo">logo</span></a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav"> 
        <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Actions <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Action 2</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>

        <li><a href="#">Posts</a></li>  

        <form class="navbar-form navbar-left search-form" role="search" action="/home/search" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="get"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="✓">
          <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" name="q" id="q" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
          </div>
        </form>      
      </ul>

      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">    
          <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" id="notification-circle" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                <i title="Notifications" class="fa fa-circle fa-lg"></i>

            </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="notifications-ul">
              <li><a href="#">All Notifications...</a></li>
            </ul>  
          </li>

          <li><a href="#">Help</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Logout</a></li>

      </ul>

    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

Currently this nav gets collapsed on xs devices, and that is a problem, because the notifications button will light up with a number when there are new notifications, and that information will not show up to the user if the notification is collapsed.

Attempt 1:
I tried to move the notifications into the `navbar-header`, but that renders the notifications to the left of the search, which is not acceptable.

Attempt 2:
I also tried to create two notifications - one visible in xs in the header, one hidden in xs, but it causes all kind of weirdnesses - the dropdown list item shows as a separate circle in the mobile view, for example. Here is one variant of my attempt:

```
  <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" role="navigation">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="/"><span class="logo">logo</span></a>
      <ul class="navbar-brand visible-xs-inline">    
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" id="notification-circle" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
              <i title="Notifications" class="fa fa-circle fa-lg"></i>
          </a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="notifications-ul">
            <li><a href="#">All Notifications...</a></li>
          </ul>  
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav"> 
        <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Actions <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Action 2</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>

        <li><a href="#">Posts</a></li>  

        <form class="navbar-form navbar-left search-form" role="search" action="/home/search" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="get"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="✓">
          <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" name="q" id="q" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
          </div>
        </form>      
      </ul>


      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">  
        <li><a href="#">Help</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Logout</a></li>
      </ul>

      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right hidden-xs">    
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" id="notification-circle" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
              <i title="Notifications" class="fa fa-circle fa-lg"></i>
          </a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="notifications-ul">
            <li><a href="#">All Notifications...</a></li>
          </ul>  
        </li>
      </ul>

    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

Here is the bootply link: http://www.bootply.com/SZbrMZoiXq

How can I make the notifications dropdown not collapse in mobile devices?

For instance, is there a class in bootstrap that skips collapse like 'no-collapse' that I can apply to the nav I want to skip collapsing?

Comment: I hope you get an answer dude. I tried but CSS (Bootstrap especially) is not my forte. I found something about disabling responsive behavior in bootstrap, but i don't know how you could do that selectively.